# Data Grid View data binding with List

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am facing an issue where I am trying to bind a List of object with three data grid. I got three classes DashboardResultSet, Resultset, DetailResultSet.

DashboardResultSet Class has the following code:

```
public class DashboardResultSet
{
    public string TestType { get; set; }
    public string SuccessfulExeceution { get; set; }
    public string FailedExeceution { get; set; }
    public string FailedCsvTest { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }

    public BindingList<ResultSet> _ResultSet = new BindingList<ResultSet>();

    public BindingList<ResultSet> ResultSet { get { return _ResultSet; } }
}
```

ResultSet Class have the same Binding List for DetailResultset. I am populating my objects and adding it to the binding list and then assiging it like that

```
dashboardResultSetDataGridView.DataSource = dashboardResultSets;
resultSetDataGridView.DataSource = dashboardResultSets;
resultSetDataGridView.DataMember = "ResultSet";
detailResultSetDataGridView.DataSource = dashboardResultSets;
detailResultSetDataGridView.DataMember = "DetailResultSet";// Error Cannot create the Child list
```

detailResultSetDataGridView is unable to find the dataMember DetailResultSet.

The List hierarchy will be 
DashBoard is main list which contain the lists of ResultSets and each ResultSets contain List of DetailResultSet. There are three DataGridView. The first two are populating but for the third on I am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to member "DetailResultSet", but there is no such property in class `DashboardResultSet`.

Comment: ResultSet Class have a Property of DetailResultSet

Comment: @user1071222: You might have then the wrong binding for `detailResultSetDataGridView.DataSource = dashboardResultSets;`? You have to bind it to the SelectedItem of resultSetDataGridView with a Path set to "ResultSet".

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Can Give an Example  for this . It will really help.

Comment: @user1071222: Is it WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @user1071222: It should work this way: `dataGridView1.DataSource = new Binding("DetailsResultSet", dataGridView1, "SelectedValue");`

Answer (score 0):

How about you could try

```
detailResultSetDataGridView.DataSource = dashboardResultSets.ResultSet;
detailResultSetDataGridView.DataMember = "DetailResultSet"
```

Comment: I cannot try this one because dashboardResultSets is a lists of list so what you are suggesting it will be implemented like that dashboardResultSets[0].ResultSet